# Colocar extras en un Preference Intent Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando Preferences en Android y me estoy topando con un detalle al tratar de usar `Intent` en un `PreferenceScreen`, y esto es que cuando inicializo la actividad debo recibir un dato extra, pero no he podido lograr esto.

Anexo mi XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Editar">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.usuario.hey"
        android:targetClass="com.example.usuario.hey.Activity.bloqueados"/>

</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Bloquear">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.usuario.hey"
        android:targetClass="com.example.usuario.hey.Activity.echar" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Cuando le doy clic en **Editar** se abrirá la actividad y este debe de recibir un dato extra, hasta ahorita es podido mandar extras a la clase `PreferenceActivity`

```
package com.example.usuario.hey.utils;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.usuario.hey.R;


public class SettingsActivity2 extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private String key;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyc");
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    SettingsActivity2.PreferenceFrag mPreferenceFrag =  new SettingsActivity2.PreferenceFrag();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,mPreferenceFrag);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    setTitle("Confirurar Perfil");
}
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

}
```

Fragment:

```
public static class PreferenceFrag extends PreferenceFragment {

    String key;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefereces2);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SettingsActivity2.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Intenta agregar por ejemplo `android:data="mi dato extra"` dentro del intent en el _xml_ y en tu actividad escribe `getIntent().getDataString()` para recibirlo.

Comment: @x4mp73r ya intente esa forma, pero es una variable que debo enviar y no un dato estático